# How does HelpDesk software monitor and handle emails?

Tags: email

I know this is an big open question, but I'm more interested in the email functionality of a helpdesk.

If I were to build an online web application / help desk for my site how does the email monitoring work? How would the application retrieve the emails and create or update a ticket based on the ticket ID in the subject line?

I've never understood this and considering the attempt.

Comment: what? I don't even know what you're asking. It's like asking "how to make a program". Be a little more specific please.

Comment: Some helpdesks provide you with a special email address that you forward your mail to. Others run a service in the background that connects to mailboxes via POP/IMAP and picks emails up, I wrote an app that [does both](https://www.jitbit.com/web-helpdesk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign some email addresses to the application, then set up email handling to route messages for that address to the application. This can be something simple like running fetchmail to pull email from the inbox on the email server and piping it to the application. Or you can update your email server to forward messages to the helpdesk server and set up an MTA like postfix to accept the messages and pipe them to the helpdesk application.

There are 100's of open source helpdesk applications, so I would recommend finding one in your language of choice and adding a feature rather than re-implementing this one feature. Handling email properly is very difficult because the specs are detailed and confusing, and you'll get a bunch of email that doesn't follow the specs.

If you just want to understand how it works, try setting up one of the open source applications and running some email through it. Turn on debugging and you can then find and read all of the code. [Request Tracker (RT)](http://bestpractical.com/rt) is one option. [rt-mailgate](http://bestpractical.com/docs/rt/latest/rt-mailgate.html) is the program that handles email. The basic instructions for setting up email aliases are covered in the [README](http://bestpractical.com/docs/rt/latest/README.html) in step 10.

Comment: Thank you Jim. I just needed a push on understanding. The application actually connecting to and retrieving the messages is what I misunderstood.